# pdo phpmyadmin no error: insert into is doubled each time

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-insert, virtualhost

After a long google search with many different terms, I come to you with a blocking non error...

I used to prog a lot in PHP and come back for a personal project.

About the non error, the following code insert what I need in database, but twice each time, and I need it to be done once only.

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=finance_data;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$bdd->query("INSERT INTO t_budget(budget_id, budget_year, budget_month, budget_status, budget_balance) VALUES(NULL, 2022, 3, \"pending\", 6000.00)");
?>
```

I've erased everything else on this page to get a clear error somewhere, but nothing to do. I've started web searches and finished here. I've found 2-3 nearly similar issues but offered solutions does not work for me.

Tell me if you need more details on this misterious non error and if you have any clue on what to do.
Thanks

*EDIT*
I found this in the server access log when running the page:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:07:20 +0200] "GET /add_vhost.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5282
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:07:20 +0200] "GET /img/gifLogo.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 281
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:07:20 +0200] "GET /img/pngWrench.png HTTP/1.1" 404 281
::1 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:08:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [23/Sep/2021:22:08:43 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

There is two ::1 call, then I changed the httpd-vhosts.conf to target the localhost to my project folder and it runs as expected (and really much more quicker) => the issue comes from the virtual host configuration.
Now it runs correctly, but I wish to access localhost page and my project index separately.
Do you have an idea where to look at?

Comment: The abobe code will insert one record only. You must call the php file multiple times from another page.

Comment: Check your server access log to see if the script is being called more than once.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for the suggestion, this is the only page index.php and really no other in this folder therefore -> no call or include; this seems to be host configuration issue.